# Why is there no WORD_BIT in limits.h on Linux?

Tags: linux, c, header-file

From the manpage `man limits.h`:

```
       {WORD_BIT}
             Number of bits in an object of type int.
             Minimum Acceptable Value: 32
```

However if I run a simple program:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", WORD_BIT);
  return 0;
}
```

However when trying to compile with gcc (`gcc file.c -o file`) I get the following:

```
error: ‘WORD_BIT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

How come this is not defined on my system, and where else can I find this information (in a C program)?

My system:

- Fedora 36 (Silverblue)
- gcc version 12.2.1 20220819 (Red Hat 12.2.1-1) (GCC)
- ldd (GNU libc) 2.35

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I’m not sure this is documented, but with the GNU C library you need to set `_GNU_SOURCE` to get `WORD_BIT`:

```
$ gcc -include limits.h -E - <<<"WORD_BIT" | tail -n1
WORD_BIT

$ gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -include limits.h -E - <<<"WORD_BIT" | tail -n1
32
```

You should really [use `sysconf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sysconf.html):

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("%ld\n", sysconf(_SC_WORD_BIT));
}
```

or, [as recommended in the GNU C library documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Examples-of-Sysconf.html):

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
#ifdef WORD_BIT
  printf("%d\n", WORD_BIT);
#else
  printf("%ld\n", sysconf(_SC_WORD_BIT));
#endif
}
```

(As for why this appears in `man limits.h`, this man page is [the POSIX reference for `limits.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html), and doesn’t necessarily document the C library on your system exactly. You can see this by looking at the section of the man page — the “P” suffix indicates that it’s POSIX documentation.)

You could use `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` instead; `CHAR_BIT` is always defined. What’s more, POSIX extends the C standard and specifies that `CHAR_BIT` is 8, so if you assume POSIX, you could use `sizeof(int) * 8`.

Answer (score 4):

The `gcc` has a set of builtin defines. The one you looking for is `__SIZEOF_INT__`

Full list of defines is in the documentation: 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

The pro-con of using these instead of those defined in `limits.h` is that the defines built into compiler are built into compiler - they are absolutely correct for this particular platform but are tied to this particular brand of compilers.

But for size of the `int` it is much easier to use `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: But `sizeof` (and ``__SIZEOF_x__``) values are numbers of bytes,  and the OP seems to want number of *bits.*

Comment: `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` then.

Comment: There's also `__INT_WIDTH__`.

Comment: Regarding `__INT_WIDTH__`, note the following from the documentation: “Defined to the bit widths of the corresponding types. They exist to make the implementations of `limits.h` and `stdint.h` behave correctly. You should not use these macros directly; instead, include the appropriate headers. Some of these macros may not be defined on particular systems if GCC does not provide a `stdint.h` header on those systems.”